# Extract some words in string (java)

Tags: java, regex

From the below string, I need `NUM = 12122` and `CheckFrom = 02453226170` only

```
String s="shopNumber = \"shop 1\", NUM = \"12122\", Reference = \"NUM1\", CheckFrom = \"02453226170\""
```

how can I do this using regular expression and replaceall function of String class?

Comment: Didn't quite understand what is to be done here (how you picked NUM and CheckFrom from String s).

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use Pattern and Matcher instead (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html) ?

Comment: the strings you want to extract aren't even part of your source string.

Comment: i tried as below      String s = "{shopNumber = \"shop 1\", NUM = \"12122\", Reference = \"NUM1\", CheckFrom = \"02453226170\"}";
  System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\"|[^CheckFrom =|^NUM=\\d*]",""));                                                  Output:                                                             hoNmer = ho 1 NUM = 12122 eerece = NUM1 CheckFrom = 02453226170                                                         But i want only NUM = 12122 CheckFrom = 02453226170

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Matcher.find](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) would make this task a lot easier to extract out the name/value pairs. Essentially you are looking for the pattern `word = "number"`:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\w+) = \"(\\d+)\"").matcher(s);
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
while (m.find()) {
   builder.append(m.group(1));
   builder.append("=");
   builder.append(m.group(2));
   builder.append(" ");
}
```

`m.group(1)` relates to the first [captured group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html), (i.e. the match from the word `\w+`)

Builder contains:

```
NUM=12122 CheckFrom=02453226170
```

**Update:** 
From your question in the comments, you could use instead:

```
Pattern.compile("(NUM = \"\\d+\").*( CheckFrom = \"\\d+\")")
```

and append the 2 groups together to get your `String`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a doubt.                                                              String     s="{shopNumber=shop1,NUM=12122,Reference=NUM1,CheckFrom=02453226170,Re    f=558778};                                                    Here, i want replace all with space except NUM=12122 CheckFrom=02453226170.                                              Resultant string should be s= NUM=12122 CheckFrom=02453226170 only;
can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: I've updated my example above. You can use a `StringBuilder` to 'build up' the `String`.

Comment: You are awesome!!.is it possible to simplify the code,with the below                    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(NUM=\\d+)|(CheckFrom=\\d+)").matcher(s);                                         can you tell me how you are applying the group(1) and group(2)?